# Variable being calculated in one method isn't going to another

Tags: java

I'm taking a Java class and I've been working on this program that is to calculate credit card balance based on information input through a GUI. In my output Finance Charge, New Balance, and New Payment Due are all coming out as 0. I've tried adding 5 to pinpoint where I messed up and it seems that "balance" isn't being referenced correctly when calculating `newBalance`. I assume that Finance Charge also has the same issue but fixing balance will help me fix that as well.

```
//calculates balance
        public float calculateBalance()
        {
            balance = previousBalance + currentPurchases - payments - creditsReturns + lateFees+ 5;

            return balance;
        }

        //sets finance charge
        public void setFinanceCharge(float financeCharge)
        {
            double periodicRate;
            periodicRate = .12/12;
            float d = (float)periodicRate;
            financeCharge = balance * d;
        }

        //gets finance charge
        public float getFinanceCharge()
        {
            return financeCharge;
        }

    //Method to calculate new balance
    public float calculateNewBalance()
    {
        //calculate the new balance
        newBalance = balance+financeCharge+5;

        return newBalance;
    }

    //setes new payment due
    public void setpaymentDue(double newPayment)
    {
        newPayment = newBalance * .10;
        this.paymentDue = (float)newPayment;            
    }

    //gets new payment due
    public float getpaymentDue()
    {
        return paymentDue;
    }

    //method to display results
    public void displayOutput()
    {
        if (overCreditLimit == 0)
        {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                "The Customer number is: " + customerNumber + "\n" +
                "The Customer name is: " + customerName + "\n" + 
                "The Credit Limit is: " + creditLimit + "\n" +
                "The Previous Balance is: " + previousBalance + "\n" + 
                "The Current Purchases is: " + currentPurchases + "\n" +
                "The Payments is: " + payments + "\n" +
                "The Credits/Returns is: " + creditsReturns + "\n" + 
                "The Late Fees is: " + lateFees + "\n" + 
                "The Finance Charge is: " + financeCharge + "\n" + 
                "The New Balance is: " + newBalance + "\n" +
                "The New Payment Due is: " + paymentDue + "\n");
        }
        else
        {
            overCreditAmount = newBalance - creditLimit - 25;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You are " + overCreditAmount + " dollars over your credit limit,"
                    + " a $25 fee has been charged to your new balance");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "The Customer number is: " + customerNumber + "\n" +
                    "The Customer name is: " + customerName + "\n" + 
                    "The Credit Limit is: " + creditLimit + "\n" +
                    "The Previous Balance is: " + previousBalance + "\n" + 
                    "The Current Purchases is: " + currentPurchases + "\n" +
                    "The Payments is: " + payments + "\n" +
                    "The Credits/Returns is: " + creditsReturns + "\n" + 
                    "The Late Fees is: " + lateFees + "\n" + 
                    "The Finance Charge is: " + financeCharge + "\n" + 
                    "The Amount over Credit Limit is: " + overCreditAmount + "\n" + 
                    "The New Balance is: " + newBalance + "\n" +
                    "The New Payment Due is: " + paymentDue + "\n");
        }
    }
```

Comment: To figure out the issue, I would suggest running the methods inside calculateNewBalance instead of calling the varibles. For example, for balance, call calculateBalance() instead, and see what happens.

Comment: If it does not work, I would suggest creating a local varible within the method to take the place of balance, and see if that works. If it does not, then there may be an issue with the code you are not showing.

Answer (score 0):

One way I see to solve the issue is to run methods within the calculateNewMethod method. For example.

```
public float calculateNewBalance () {
   newBalance = calculateBalance() + getFinanceCharge();
   return newBalance;
}
```

I would also suggest avoiding code where you modify private class varibles and return them within the same method, it make more sense to have one method which modifies it, and one to return the varible.